# Checking whether an Array[A] is sorted?

Tags: arrays, scala, functional-programming

While working through a problem found in 'Functional Programming in Scala':

> Implement isSorted, which checks whether an Array[A] is sorted according to a given comparison function:

```
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordered: (A,A) => Boolean): Boolean
```

While comparing my answer to the below solution provided by the author(s):

```
  // Exercise 2: Implement a polymorphic function to check whether
  // an `Array[A]` is sorted
  def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], gt: (A,A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def go(n: Int): Boolean =
      if (n >= as.length-1) true
      else if (gt(as(n), as(n+1))) false
      else go(n+1)

    go(0)
  }
```

I am getting confused by the following line of code: `else if (gt(as(n), as(n+1))) false`

I thought when using a function as a parameter in Scala, one would need to actually define a separate function outside the scope of the current function (i.e. have another function defined that does what `gt` would need to do)? I don't see `gt` defined anywhere else, so how is it able to provide a `Boolean` value to use  in `isSorted`?

Are my assumptions correct, or am I completely something missing here with using functions as parameters? A detailed explanation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, `gt` is a function passed to `isSorted` as an argument;
Let's compare it to any other argument, say `a: Int`. Let's look at the following function:

```
def increaseByOne(a: Int): Int = a + 1
```

Your question about `gt` is equivalent to asking: "**How can `increaseByOne` use `a` if `a` is never assigned a value?**". Obviously, the *caller* of the `increaseByOne` method would have to pass some value as the value of `a`, but the very concept of arguments is naming some value that is provided into the method.

The same goes for `gt`: it's an *argument* of `isSorted`. In the code you presented, we don't see the *caller* of `isSorted`, so we don't see any example of what `gt` might be - but obviously the *implementation* of `isSorted` need not assume anything about how and where `gt` is created, it is passed as an argument and therefore can be used in `isSorted`.

We can imagine a usage such as:

```
isSorted(Array(1,3,6), (a: Int, b: Int) => a > b)
```

Here, `(a: Int, b: Int) => a > b` would be the value of `gt`.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the detailed explanation. One small follow-up question, does the function argument need to be defined while `isSorted` is called (i.e. in the example you just gave)? Or can the function be defined elsewhere, and directly passed in as an argument to `isSorted`?